# ERROR - argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA in R

Tags: r

Am trying to compute mean for grouped variables for an imported CSV file using group_by/summerise but only the first variable(column) returns mean but the rest of columns return NAs, When I check variable types using str(Cluster_kpis), datatype for the columns show numeric yet R claims they are not numeric. Where could be the issue.  codes are below and screenshot of the data source[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVNkk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBAix.png)

Comment: please click the links to access the code and source data images

Comment: There are empty columns in the data which are imported as empty character in R. `mean(as.numeric(c(1, "", 3, NA, 5)), na.rm=T)` should work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Please edit your question to include [reproducible data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and dont add data as screenshots

Comment: Thanks Andre, I have replaced [c(1, "", 3, NA, 5))] from your example above with  my variable 'Data Volume (PS)_MTN(MB)' but I get "NAN"s as out and a warning that NAs have been introduced by coercion . By the way , i used read_csv function for importation of source data to R

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you every one for trying to help. I have gotten the solution. I had to first manually convert my columns in the CSV file to numbers before importing to R. Although it looks not the ultimate solution for such an issue, for now it helps

Answer (score 0):

Issue was my CSV file I imported to R required me to format all variable columns to "NUMBER" before importing to R. This is not the best solution but for now, it works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).